# Load the data of a table into a DataGridView created at run-time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledb

I'm trying to create a DataGridView at runtime whenever I press a button.
I also want to present the data from a table in my database.

When I press the Button that should create a DataGridView and show the data, but it just does nothing. It doesn't create the DataGridView.

Here is my code (the table is called "supplies"):

```
public partial class managerpage : Form
{
    int idWorkersDB = 0;
    int idAccountsDB = 1;
    int idSuppliersDB = 2;
    int idOtherDB = 3;
    public static DataGridView workersView = new DataGridView();
    public static DataGridView suppliesView = new DataGridView();
    public static DataGridView accountsView = new DataGridView();
    int clickedID;

    private void picBoxSuppliers_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        suppliesView.Location = new Point(59, 51);
        suppliesView.Size = new Size(749, 399);
        
        clickedID = idSuppliersDB;
        dataDBPanel.Visible = true;
        dataDBPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        
        titleDataLbl.Text = "Suppliers Data";
        titleDataLbl.Left = (this.Width - titleDataLbl.Width) / 2;
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\project\FUCKINGVISUALSTUDIOISSOSHIT\loginData.mdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM supplies", con);
        con.Open();
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        cmd.Fill(tbl);
        con.Close();

        suppliesView.DataSource = tbl;
        suppliesView.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding most of the code, but I suspect you never add that suppliesView (a datagridview?) to the form. Here is a sample code that works wonderfully well:

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select * from Customers", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        t.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
    }

    
    var f = new Form();
    var dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=t};
    f.Controls.Add(dgv);
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Hi :)
It is finally working, and I added more code so everyone will understand my issue a bit more.
I had an accident when writing this code, as you can see I haven't added the "this.control.add(suppliesView)" and also I wanted to place that on a panel that is covering the whole screen, and when I was creating the panel the datagridview hid behind it... But what really fixed the problem is the "this.control.add(suppliesView)" that you added in your code... Thank you very much! You helped me.